# discord.py doesn't play sequentially moultiple sounds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so i created a "command" that is basically playing an audio file when its written. But my problem is that its giving me an error like this:

```
raise ClientException('Already connected to a voice channel.')
discord.errors.ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel.
```

my code is here:

```
if (".avocado") in content:
        ...
        *bunch of code that doesn't effect the voice*
        ...

        await message.channel.send((f"avocados from mexico: %d" %final))

        channel = message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.connect()
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:\Program Files\Python38\pffmpeg\pffmpeg.exe", source="avocados_from_mexico.mp3"))
        voicest = 1
```

Ty for any sort of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the bot's voice and check if it's already connected or not:

```py
from discord.utils import get

(...)

if (".avocado") in content:
    (...)
    await message.channel.send((f"avocados from mexico: %d" %final))

    channel = message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=message.guild)

    if not voice and not voice.is_connected():
        vc = await channel.connect()  
    vc.play(...)
```

References :

- `voice` : [`discord.VoiceClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient)
- `voice.is_connected()` : [`discord.VoiceClient.is_connected()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=is_connected)
- `get` : [`discord.utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get)

Comment: yeah, but im not using bot.command i am using client.event so it isn't working, and more problem is that i cant use bot.command if i am using a client.event (which is essential for me).

Comment: You can replace `bot` with `client` and `ctx.guild` to `message.guild` ;)